# why results are different of the following query

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Select 
    d.CompanyName, c.SubTotal, b.Weight 
from 
    ProductAW b 
JOIN 
    SalesOrderDetail a ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID 
JOIN 
    SalesOrderHeader c ON c.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID 
JOIN 
    CustomerAW d ON d.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
WHERE
    d.CompanyName IN ('Good Toys', 'Transport Bikes') 
ORDER BY 
    c.SubTotal ASC;
```

// Output

```
CompanyName        SubTotal    Weight
Transport Bikes     602.19     13213.08
Transport Bikes     602.19        88.00
Good Toys           880.35      1061.40
Good Toys           880.35       988.83
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    d.CompanyName, c.SubTotal, b.Weight 
FROM 
    ProductAW b 
JOIN 
    SalesOrderDetail a ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID 
JOIN 
    SalesOrderHeader c ON c.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID 
JOIN 
    CustomerAW d ON d.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
WHERE 
    d.CompanyName IN ('Good Toys', 'Transport Bikes') 
ORDER BY 
    c.SubTotal DESC;
```

Result:

```
CompanyName     SubTotal    Weight
Good Toys         880.35     1061.40
Good Toys         880.35      988.83
Transport Bikes   602.19    13213.08
Transport Bikes   602.19       88.00
```

Difference in both queries is only `ASC` and `DESC` keyword on the `ORDER BY` clause.

Please explain why `Weight` column also gets sorted with `SubTotal`.

Cheers,

Comment: `ASC` == Ascending, `DESC` == Descending, exactly like in the result. Either there is no actual problem, or I am missing something here

Comment: Look at the first record of first query its Transport Bikes 602.19  13213.08  However the last record of second query is Transport Bikes 602.19  88.00   . Why the last record of second query is not " Transport Bikes 602.19  13213.08 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `weight` column is not sorted. The sorting happened by `Subtotal` ascending or descending
I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: Weight might be any order, it is simply undefined and might depend on previous processing steps by the database to materialize the query result.

Comment: isn't it usually in the order it appears in the table? The cross join happens first, and then filtered.. or am I wrong? @MarkRotteveel

Comment: My point is that it is undefined if it is not explicitly specified in an `ORDER BY`. It might be storage order (and for simple queries it usually is), but it might just as well not be. Saying it is storage order clouds the issue, as it could depend on the access path of the query. For example it could also be an artefact of a sort of a previous step in the query, the index retrieval order etc.

Comment: Do we have a way to sort the results exactly in reverse order as they appear in first result set?

Comment: @jNet not necessarily.. as other comments have suggested, it will depend upon the plan of execution of the sql query - and is mostly undefined if they are two same.

Comment: @jNet you can modify `Transport Bikes 602.19  13213.08` weight to 0 and it will still show you the same way. only the result will show 0 weight this time.

Answer (score 3):

The results are same, just the **order of records is changed** in the result as the **first query is showing the results in ascending order** while the **second is showing them in descending order**.

**Update**
Weight column is not being sorted along with the **SubTotal** it's just a coincidence that both of them are being shown in the sorted order. And to make sure of that just test the query results by inserting another record e.g. `Transport Bikes 602.19  222222.00` this newly added record will distort the whole ordering of `weight` and I can assure you of that.

Answer (score 3):

The weight column is NOT sorted. Their ordering is *undefined*. It is just a coincidence that they appear to be sorted.

Depending on the implementation of the database engine, when the sorting order is not explicitly defined, rows might appear in the order they were inserted in the table. Or not. It really depends on the implementation.

In general you should not make assumptions about the ordering of columns if you have not specified an ordering explicitly.

If you want the first query to be in the order you showed, and to make that ordering *well-defined* then change the `ORDER BY` clause to this:

```
ORDER BY c.SubTotal, Weight DESC
```

And then, if you want to reverse the ordering in the second query, then use this:

```
ORDER BY c.SubTotal DESC, Weight
```

Note that ASC is optional, usually it is the default direction of ordering.

Comment: Do we have a way to sort the results exactly in reverse order as they appear in first results set?

Comment: Sort of: `ORDER BY c.SubTotal DESC, Weight`. I say "sort of", because the sorting order on `Weight` was not defined in the first query. Probably you want to make the ordering of Weight well-defined in the first query like this: `ORDER BY c.SubTotal, Weight DESC`. Note that `ASC` is optional, usually it is the default ordering direction. I updated my answer with this added info.